# Formatting text

Tags: java, string

I have a couple questions. I'm trying to format my text into a simple format to read. I currently have:

```
 MAC11053hrsECO20133hrsECO20233hrsANT20003hrsPSY20123hrsSYG20003hrsACG20213hrsACG20713hrsCGS21003hrsECO20133hrsECO20233hrsECO34013hrsMAC22333hrsSTA20233hrsACG31313hrsECO34113hrsFIN34033hrsMAN30253hrsMAR30233hrsBUL31303hrsGEB33753hrsMAR32033hrsACG31413hrsACG33613hrsACG44013hrsACG46513hrsACG48033hrsMAN47203hrsACG49033hrsACG49043hrsACG49703hrsENC11013hrsMAC11053hrsECO20133hrsENC11023hrsECO20233hrsACG20213hrsSPC16083hrsACG20713hrsECO34013hrsCGS21003hrsACG31313hrsFIN34033hrsMAR30233hrsECO34113hrsMAN30253hrsACG31413hrsACG33613hrsBUL31303hrsACG44013hrsGEB33753hrsMAR32033hrsACG46513hrsACG48033hrsMAN47203hrs
```

I want :

```
MAC1105 3hrs
ECO2013 3hrs
ect.
```

So far my code sucks! I have been trying to figure this out but I can't seem to use any of the other posts to solve what seems to be a fairly simple issue. I essentially am reading each line and then trying to insert `" "` and `"\n"` in order to format the output. I wanted to use a for loop `int d < line.length();` but it seems that my understanding is completely wrong.  In my text doc it shows all these course codes in about 8 lines yet it seems to all be on the same line (I think). How can I set this up?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Indentation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File inFile = new File("/Users/Richard/Desktop/resources/Out.txt");

        File outFile = new File("/Users/Richard/Desktop/resources/finally.txt");

        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(outFile);
        PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(fWriter);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String s = line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

            for (int d = 1; d < 61; d++) {
                sb.insert(d * 7, " ");
                sb.insert(d * 12, "\n");
            }

            pWriter.print(sb.toString());
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
        sc.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Consider MAC11053hrs, MAC is always 3 digits code? 11005 is always 4? the hours do not go over 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the concept of **regular expression** very useful here.  Read up more about it from some good tutorials such as [this one by Oracle/Sun](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Also you will need to make some assumption about the input.  For example, the course code is always three "word characters" followed by four digits.  The duration (`hrs`) is always a one or two digit number followed by the string "hrs", etc.  Once you have that, you can code the regular expression like
what I have below:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ScanText1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "MAC11053hrsECO20133hrsECO20233hrsANT20003hrsPSY20123hrsSYG20003hrsACG20213hrsACG20713hrsCGS21003hrsECO20133hrsECO20233hrsECO34013hrsMAC22333hrsSTA20233hrsACG31313hrsECO34113hrsFIN34033hrsMAN30253hrsMAR30233hrsBUL31303hrsGEB33753hrsMAR32033hrsACG31413hrsACG33613hrsACG44013hrsACG46513hrsACG48033hrsMAN47203hrsACG49033hrsACG49043hrsACG49703hrsENC11013hrsMAC11053hrsECO20133hrsENC11023hrsECO20233hrsACG20213hrsSPC16083hrsACG20713hrsECO34013hrsCGS21003hrsACG31313hrsFIN34033hrsMAR30233hrsECO34113hrsMAN30253hrsACG31413hrsACG33613hrsBUL31303hrsACG44013hrsGEB33753hrsMAR32033hrsACG46513hrsACG48033hrsMAN47203hrs";

        Pattern p 
            = Pattern.compile(
                "(?<courseCode>\\w{3}\\d{4})" /* courseCode: 3 word chars plus 4 digits */
                + "(?<hrs>\\d{1,2})hrs"       /* hrs: 1 or 2 digits and then "hrs" */
              );

        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            String courseCode = m.group("courseCode");
            int    hrs        = Integer.parseInt(m.group("hrs"));
            System.out.format("%s %dhrs%n", courseCode, hrs);
        }
    }

}
```

The output of the problem would be something like:

```
MAC1105 3hrs
ECO2013 3hrs
ECO2023 3hrs
ANT2000 3hrs
PSY2012 3hrs
...
```

Comment: what could I do about this error? Illegal repetition near index 20
(?<courseCode>\w{3}\w{d})(?<hrs>\d{1,2})hrs
                    ^

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my original post.  Just fixed it.  It was in the line for `p`  I updated my post above.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Its amazing how many ways there are to do something.I have honestly been trying all day using various methods but I just couldn't get there.I'm happy you used regex!

Comment: I added better comments for the regex in the code (in the lines for `p`).  This should make it easier to read.

Comment: regex is fun.  You will like it :-)

Comment: Im using pWriter to output the string to a file.I usually do `pWriter.print(" ")` but I notice you have the format there.Is there a good way to output to a fine with `pWrite.format` ? i'm trying but I keep getting blank files.